# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable in Python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

I wrote this code and for some reason it always gives the error

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

This is the code:

```
V = self.vertex(QF)
      s = V[0] - 100
      e = V[0] + 100
      while s != e:
          p = QFS(a,b,c,s)
          x = (p[0] + 100.0)/10.0
          y = ((p[1] + 100.0)*-1)/10.0
          canvas.create_line(x-1,y-1,x+1,y+1)
          s += .1
```

I am graphing a porabola BTW
vertex() and QFS() return tuples

Comment: Show the full traceback. Debug your program, for example by printing all your (intermediate) variables.

Comment: Clearly `vertex` and `QFS` *don't* return tuples. That or this isn't all your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to print out your intermediate values to check what they are. I can’t tell which one but I know that either your `v` or `p` value is an integer and is not a list or iterable object.